USB over IP speed much lower than it could be
I am working on a project that uses Linux USBIP to work with USB devices connected to a remote server. So far, the server and the client are computers connected to the same router.
The problem is that when working with a USB 3.2 Flash drive, the maximum speed only reaches about 40 MB/s. With a USB2.0 flash drive, and then the speed is only ~9.8 MB/s. But my NICs supports speed 1 Gb/s.
Server: Linux Mint 21.3; kernel version: 5.15.0
Client: Linux Mint 20.3; kernel version: 5.15.0
Ethernet speed: NICs: 1 Gigabite Ethernet;
program iperf give me that results
$ iperf -c <server_ip>

------------------------------------------------------------
Client connecting to <server_ip>, TCP port 5001
TCP window size: 85.0 KByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------
[  1] local <client> port 57200 connected with <server_ip> port 5001
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  1] 0.0000-10.0286 sec  1.10 GBytes   940 Mbits/sec

Therefore, the High-speed speed must be fully supported. Yes, I know that SuperSpeed and above cannot be fully supported on this NICs, but even 1 GB/s would be enough
Driver: lsusb shows me, that device is using vhci driver with 5000M for USB 3.2 and 480M for USB 2.0
So, what needs to be done so that the devices start working at the maximum speed provided by the network card, if at all possible

What is the throughput of the flash device itself? Are you transferring a large file, or a whole bunch of small files? Also, remember that USB/IP has overhead too.

But my NICs supports speed 1 Gb/s.  That's one gigabit per second, or about 100 megabytes per second when networking protocol overhead is accounted for.  40 MB/sec is pretty good speed given the likely packet latencies and USB/IP overhead.  but even 1 GB/s would be enough  One gigabyte per second is not going to happen over a one gigabit per second link.


but even 1 GB/s would be enough

the comments already point this out: You get 1 Gb/s = (1/8) GB/s. So, your expectations are off by a factor of 8.
Also, remember that USB and Ethernet are fundamentally different protocols: In USB, the host needs to ask every device for data; devices do not initiate transfers themselves. USB Mass Storage devices are sequential in access; so, the system will always work "host requests, device answers, only then host can request the next thing".
That's fine with a direct USB cable between the host and the device. Over a network, the roundtrip latency over the network link hence becomes a bandwidth limit.

maximum speed only reaches about 40 MB/s

That's 320 Mb/s. That's very good!
USB 3.2 Gen 1.1 supports data payloads of at most 1024 B per packet. So, that's 320 thousand network packets, in the ideal, least-overhead, scenario, per second. This is far from unheard of, but many Gigabit ethernet drivers and cards do not support general checksum offloading, some even in 2024 don't even support interrupt coalescing. So, that's a lot of CPU power that just goes into network handling!
Furthermore, because data can only be delivered after being requested by the host, you need to take into account the time the command packet needs to travel from the requesting computer to the other; for every response packet, there's a command packet, so we're at 640 kPacket/s. Not bad at all! Seeing that you're making use of a full third of the Gigabit link's time per direction with payload, and acting as if the USB storage could always saturate its 5 Gb/link, we see that we that in one direction, we make use of close to half the wire speed. So, we can conclude that it takes the USB-side system to handle the commands, forward them to the USB device, then to wait for the device to reply, receive the full reply, put it in a network packet and send it back about as long as it takes to transfer a full 1024 B packet (latency + size/speed). That is, frankly, a testament to well-structured data paths within the Linux kernel and quite the opposite of what you paint it to be (slow).
So, if you need any higher speed, then the answer is not to use USP-IP to give one computer access to a block device attached to the other via network. That's just the wrong choice!
There's much easier and faster solutions to that, which don't have to rely on encapsulating every, single, sequential USB command in a network packet. Instead, you'd be dealing with data:

If you just want to access files on the USB storage device, then obviously, use a file server. SSH (SSHfs), Samba (SMB/CIFS), NFSd (NFS)… there's multiple choices there.
If you just want access to the raw block device, use a block device protocol. Network Block Device (nbd) is relatively easy to set up; iSCSI isn't much harder. What you want depends on your application's needs.

The higher-level you can go over network, the better for speed.

Data rates in bytes are commonly expressed in factors of 1024, where data rates in bits are exclusively expressed in factors of 1000. 1GB/s is approx 8.6Gb/s not 8. Sorry to be pedantic.

Do you know definitively that USB 2.0 does not support request pipelining?

@PhilipCouling no need to apologize! The thing is, we're talking about 1000 Base-T, which has a symbol rate of exactly 125·10⁶ bd on two lanes; so, this is really 10⁹ bit/s, physically, not 2³⁰ bit/s.

@PhilipCouling yep, USB 2 and 3.2 gen 1.1 do themselves not support that at all. USB is intentionally a simple protocol. That's one of the reasons why you defintely want UASP when you attach a fast storage device to a fast host controller; it's the main advantage of hardware+software UASP support. UASP doesn't work through network.
